# How to hide or supress Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC error for blank cells in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, error-handling

$AAA = ($BBB.Columns.Item($CCC.Plan_Name).Find($DDD.Entity)).Row

Whenever a blank cell is found, it throws this error, Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC. How can I hide it so it doesn't flood my output?

I don't want to use #$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" for my whole script as it hides all errors.

Comment: maybe `try { $AAA = ($BBB.Columns.Item($CCC.Plan_Name).Find($DDD.Entity)).Row } catch { }` or `$AAA = ($BBB.Columns.Item($CCC.Plan_Name).Find($DDD.Entity)).Row 2>$null`

Comment: try and catch works. Thanks